# Identifying geometry type of layer with QGIS expressions

Tags: qgis, layers, vector, geometry, expression

**The question**

Using QGIS expression, it can occur that you want to identify the geometry-type of a layer (point, line or polygon? Multiple or single part?). This can be the case to write an expression that works for different kind of geometry types, using an if-clause - pseudocode: `if point, do A, if line, do B, if polygon, do C`.

[See here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/397498/88814) for an example (go to the expression at *B. Get list of all the angles of a line or polygon*).

**What I tried**

I looked if there is a variable of the kind `@layer_type`, but there is not. There are variables for `@layer_name` or `@layer_crs`, but not for the geometry type of the layer (see screenshot).

As in the example above, a workaround is to find out if a geometry is a polygon or not to use `if(num_rings($geometry) is null, 1, 0)`: returns 0 for polygons, 1 for lines and points.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**For features** use this expression:

```
string_to_array(geom_to_wkt($geometry),' ')[0]
```

And then you can get one [of WKT geometry type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry): *'Point'*, *'LineString'*, *'Polygon'*, *'MultiPoint'*, *'MultiLineString'*, *'MultiPolygon'*, *'GeometryCollection'* etc.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution **for features** using *a custom function* via [the Function Editor](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#function-editor)

[image: function_editor]

```py
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def geomfunction(feature, parent):
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    layer_wkb = layer.wkbType()
    layer_wkb_type = QgsWkbTypes.displayString(layer_wkb)
    return layer_wkb_type
```

Call the above function `geomfunction()` and get an output

[image: result]

Answer (score 6):

**For a layer** this is probably the most suitable expression:

```
layer_property(@layer,'geometry_type')
```

Check [QGIS Documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#layer-property) for more details.

Please keep in mind, that this expression will return strictly the geometry type of a layer, e.g. it is *'Polygon'* even though this layer contain *'MultiPolygon'* features in it.

[image: example]

Result of using the `layer_property()`
[image: result_1]

And result of using the `string_to_array(geom_to_wkt($geometry),' ')[0]` for features of the same layer
[image: result_2]

Comment: won't that just be `geometry` or `collection` for a mixed geometry layer?

Comment: Nice question, I think I need to aggregate my answers now

Comment: Three solutions, but just one option to accept - so it's a bit arbitrary which one to select. However, that does not matter, as all are by the same user - thanks, @Taras.

Comment: You are welcome, but be careful the one you choose! `layer_property` will give you simply a Polygon even though you have a MultiPolygon inside of it. Here some additional investigations are needed.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with QGIS version 3.24, [forthcoming these days](https://www.qgis.org), a new expression has been introduced that does exactly this. It works like [`geometry_type($geometry)`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#geometry-type), returning the geometry type.

> The new geometry_type function returns the high-level type of a
> geometry (i.e. ‘Point’, ‘Line’ or ‘Polygon’).

From the [Changelog for QGIS 3.24](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog324/index.html#feature-geometry-type-function).